# R Creating new data.table with specified rows of a single column from an old data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `data.table`:

```
    Month Day  Lat Long        Temperature
 1:    10  01 80.0  180 -6.383330333333309
 2:    10  01 77.5  180 -6.193327999999976
 3:    10  01 75.0  180 -6.263328333333312
 4:    10  01 72.5  180 -5.759997333333306
 5:    10  01 70.0  180 -4.838330999999976
---                                       
117020:    12  31 32.5  310 11.840003833333355
117021:    12  31 30.0  310 13.065001833333357
117022:    12  31 27.5  310 14.685003333333356
117023:    12  31 25.0  310 15.946669666666690
117024:    12  31 22.5  310 16.578336333333358
```

For every location (given by `Lat` and `Long`), I have a temperature for each day from 1 October to 31 December.

There are 1,272 locations consisting of each pairwise combination of `Lat`:

```
    Lat
1   80.0
2   77.5
3   75.0
4   72.5
5   70.0
--------
21  30.0
22  27.5
23  25.0
24  22.5
```

and `Long`:

```
Long
1   180.0
2   182.5
3   185.0
4   187.5
5   190.0
---------
49  300.0
50  302.5
51  305.0
52  307.5
53  310.0
```

I'm trying to create a `data.table` that consists of 1,272 rows (one per location) and 92 columns (one per day). Each element of that `data.table` will then contain the temperature at that location on that day.

Any advice about how to accomplish that goal without using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here we use `ChickWeights` as the data, where we use "Chick-Diet" as the equivalent of your "lat-lon", and "Time" as your "Date":

```
dcast.data.table(data.table(ChickWeight), Chick + Diet ~ Time)
```

Produces:

```
     Chick Diet 0 2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 21
 1:    18    1 1 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 2:    16    1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA
 3:    15    1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA
 4:    13    1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
 5:   ... 46 rows omitted
```

You will likely need to `lat + lon ~ Month + Day` or some such for your formula.

In the future, please make your question **[reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/2725969)** as I did here by using a built-in data set.

Comment: Wow, that's perfect. Thanks a lot for taking the time to produce that example, I'll be sure to do that on future inquiries.

Answer (score 0):

First create a date value using the `lubridate` package (I assumed year = 2014, adjust as necessary):

```
library(lubridate)
df$datetext <- paste(df$Month,df$Day,"2014",sep="-")
df$date <- mdy(df$datetext)
```

Then one option is to use the `tidyr` package to spread the columns:

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df[,-c(1:2,6)],date,Temperature)

    Lat Long 2014-10-01 2014-12-31
1  22.5  310         NA   16.57834
2  25.0  310         NA   15.94667
3  27.5  310         NA   14.68500
4  30.0  310         NA   13.06500
5  32.5  310         NA   11.84000
6  70.0  180  -4.838331         NA
7  72.5  180  -5.759997         NA
8  75.0  180  -6.263328         NA
9  77.5  180  -6.193328         NA
10 80.0  180  -6.383330         NA
```